# AngularJS Directive failing apply because $apply is already running

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%apply
```

Hi! I'm making a mini calendar standalone directive and I'm having trouble applying the changes of the months and the day. It tells me $apply is already in progress, I have google around and notice it's a problem when using it inside a compile definition object.

But preventing the $apply from running when it's already doing it didn't solve things, since it seems like its always running. Any suggestion or fixes for my issue would be appreciated :D

Controller + Directive

```
function calendarController($scope) {
    $scope.config = new Date(2013, 4, 25);
}
angular.module("calendar", []).directive('miniCalendar', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "../views/template.html",
        transclude: true,
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.currentDate = new Date();
            $scope.prev = function() {
                $scope.mCalDate = new Date($scope.mCalDate.getFullYear(), $scope.mCalDate.getMonth() - 1, $scope.mCalDate.getDay());
                $scope.updateDate($scope.mCalDate);
            };
            $scope.next = function() {
                $scope.mCalDate = new Date($scope.mCalDate.getFullYear(), $scope.mCalDate.getMonth() + 1, $scope.mCalDate.getDay());
                $scope.updateDate($scope.mCalDate);
            };
            $scope.selecting = false;
            $scope.selectDate = function() {
                $scope.selecting = !$scope.selecting;
            };
            $scope.selectDay = function(day) {
                $scope.mCalDate = day.date;
                $scope.updateDate($scope.mCalDate);
            };
            $scope.currentMonth = '';
            $scope.currentYear = '';
            $scope.days = [{
                day: "Sun"
            }, {
                day: "Mon"
            }, {
                day: "Tue"
            }, {
                day: "Wed"
            }, {
                day: "Thu"
            }, {
                day: "Fri"
            }, {
                day: "Sat"
            }];
            $scope.weeks = [];
        },
        scope: {
            mCalDate: '='
        },
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            var modelAccessor = $parse(attrs.mCalDate);
            return function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                scope.currentDate = scope.mCalDate.getDate() + '/' + Math.abs(scope.mCalDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + scope.mCalDate.getFullYear();
                var firstDayOfMonth = new Date(scope.mCalDate.getFullYear(), scope.mCalDate.getMonth(), 1).toDateString().split(' ');
                var totalDays = new Date(scope.mCalDate.getFullYear(), scope.mCalDate.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
                var firstDayIndex;
                for (var i in scope.days) {
                    if (scope.days[i].day == firstDayOfMonth[0]) {
                        firstDayIndex = i;
                    }
                }
                var allDays = [];
                var h = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < totalDays + 6; i++) {
                    if (i >= firstDayIndex && (h + 1) <= totalDays) {
                        allDays.push({
                            dayName: scope.days[new Date(scope.mCalDate.getFullYear(), scope.mCalDate.getMonth(), h + 1).getDay()].day,
                            day: ++h,
                            date: new Date(scope.mCalDate.getFullYear(), scope.mCalDate.getMonth(), h + 1)
                        });
                    } else {
                        allDays.push({});
                    }
                }
                var calendar = []
                var chunk = 7;
                for (i = 0, allDays.length; i < allDays.length; i += chunk) {
                    calendar.push({
                        week: calendar.length,
                        days: allDays.slice(i, i + chunk)
                    });
                }
                scope.weeks = calendar;
                scope.currentYear = scope.mCalDate.getFullYear();
                scope.currentMonth = scope.mCalDate.toDateString().split(' ')[1];
                scope.$watch('mCalDate', function(val) {
                    //debugger;
                });
                scope.updateDate = function(date) {
                    scope.mCalDate = date;
                    var phase = scope.$root.$$phase; //Safe applying
                    if (phase != '$apply' || phase != '$digest') {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.mCalDate = date;
                            $parse(attrs.mCalDate).assign(scope.$parent, 'config');
                        });
                    }
                };

            };

        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<mini-calendar type="text" m-cal-date="config" />
```

Template

```
<div class="miniCalendar"><label ng-click="selectDate()"><input type="text" ng-model="currentDate" disabled></label><div ng-show="selecting"><div><a><span ng-click="prev()">Prev</span></a><a><span ng-click="next()">Next</span></a><div ><span ng-bind="currentMonth">January</span>&nbsp;<span ng-bind="currentYear"></span></div></div><table><thead><tr><th ng-repeat="day in days"><span ng-bind="day.day"></span></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr ng-repeat="week in weeks"><td ng-repeat="d in week.days"><a ng-bind="d.day" ng-click="selectDay(d)">1</a></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
```

Comment: try using $timeout instead of $apply.

Comment: $timeout didn't fix my issue, maybe you could elaborate a little more(?
Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to call $apply.  Are you calling a method that runs asynchronously, and outside the angular context? If no, you don't need $apply. The digest cycle will automatically run to execute all your watch handlers after the linking phase.

Answer (score 0):

Using $timeout instead of $apply can solve $digest issue.

```
scope.updateDate = function(date) {
  $timeout(function() {
    scope.mCalDate = date;
    $parse(attrs.mCalDate).assign(scope.$parent, 'config');
  });
};
```